# Is there any way to compare each element in an array using a single loop?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, array-algorithms

I need to print the least difference between any two elements of an int array.

each element of array `A` is less than equal to its length.

```
1 <= A[i] <= A.length;
```

I have tried this below given approach in Java - 
But this takes more than 1 second to find results when array size is given ~10^5.

I think it may be a naive approach. Is there any way i can optimize it further?
Can it be done in `O(n)` time complexity?

```
static int findResult(int[] arr)
        {
                 int max =  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                 HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
                 for(int obj : arr)
                 {
                     hs.add(obj);
                 }
                if(hs.size()==1 )
                {
                    return 0;             // if all elements are same
                }
                 for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
                 {  
                     for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
                     {
                         int value = Math.abs(a[i]-a[j]);
                         if(value<max)
                         {
                            max = value;
                         }

                      }         
                }
        return max;  // returns the smallest positive difference
    }
```

Comment: You can sort the array, and then look for the smallest difference, this is then always between the current and next item.

Comment: It will work in a few cases. like 1 2 5 7 1. Sorted - 1 1 2 5 7. but will fail(worst case) - 5 2 3 1 5. sorted -1 2 3 5 5. anyway thanks :)

Comment: No, for all, since then you iterate over the "consecutive" elements, and each time calculate the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## With *1≤x<sub>i</sub>≤n*: *O(n)*

Since for every *x<sub>i</sub>* it holds that *1≤x<sub>i</sub>≤n*, it holds that, due to the *pigeonhole principle*, either all values exist exactly *once*, or a value exists *two or more times*.

In the former case, the difference is `1` (for an array larger than 1 element), in the latter case, the result is `0`, since then there are two items that are exactly equal.

We can thus iterate over the array and keep track of the numbers. If a number already exists once, we return `0`, otherwise, we return `1`, like:

```
// only if it holds that for all i, 1 <= arr[i] <= arr.length
static int findResult(int[] arr) {
    bool[] found = new bool[arr.length]
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(found[arr[i]-1]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            found[arr[i]-1] = true;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

For a random array that satisfies the condition with *n* elements, in *n!/n<sup>n</sup>* of the cases, it will return `1`, and in the other cases, it will return `0`, so the average over random input is *n!/n<sup>n</sup>*. As *n* grows larger, it becomes very unlikely that there are no "collisions", and thus, as [@YvesDaoust says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250101/is-there-any-way-to-compare-each-element-in-an-array-using-a-single-loop/53250191?noredirect=1#comment93385436_53250191), the approximation of `0` is very likely.

## Without *1≤x<sub>i</sub>≤n*: *O(n log n)*

In case we drop the constraint, we can first sort the array, and in that case, we iterate over consecutive elements:

```
static int findResult(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int dmin = arr[1] - arr[0];
    for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int d = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
        if(d < dmin) {
            if(d == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            dmin = d;
        }
    }
    return dmin;
}
```

Comment: An approximate solution is possible in O(1): `return 0`. This will be correct in a vast majority of cases ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes exactly, in *n!/n^n* it returns `1`, in the other cases it returns `0`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: added a paragraph on average result to the answer.

Comment: First one will do. since there have be that constraint(1<=arr[i]<=arr.length). It should work. Thanks man! :-)

Comment: 1 micro-optimization in your 2nd approach. You return `dmin` the moment you come to know it's `0` .

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem maybe I miss something but shouldn't the first `findResult` code should check in the if statement: `if (found[arr[i]]) return 0 else found[arr[i]] = true`? (Instead of `found[i-1]`)

Comment: @DavidWinder: well Java uses zero-based indices, and here the numbers are integers between `1` and `n`, so we shift it with 1 to `0` to `n-1`. But indeed, this is a bit "language specific".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And still, at the first iteration `i=0` so java can do `found[-1]`?? Maybe this should be `found[arr[i] -1]`?

Comment: @DavidWinder: I made a mistake, it should be `found[arr[i]-1]`, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `A`'s are integer, otherwise the condition `1 <= A[i] <= A.len` has no relevance.

Then there is an `O(n)` solution by using an histogram.

1. declare an array of counters of size `A.length`;
2. count the multiplicities of the elements of `A`;
3. scan this histogram to find the closest non-empty bins.

---

Note that this solution assumes that only nonzero differences are considered. If zero difference counts, then Willem's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

(Adding to the above answers)

If you need to do this with O(1) extra space, you can use the following trick on the input sequence A:

```
for a in A[1...n]:        // a is an element in A; A is 1-indexed; 1 <= a <= n
    if M < A[a % M]:
        return 0
    A[a % M] += M
return 1
```

Here M (> n) is such that M + n doesn't overflow. The trick can be easily modified to use instead an M which is less than -n.

Caveats:

1. Requires random (i.e. O(1)) access to the elements of A.
2. Not cache-friendly.